# Duplicate removal from an array conditionally i.e. different revision number then not a duplicate

Tags: javascript, arrays

I found the function written below it's perfect for removing straight duplicates where rows are a complete match and put into a separate array for later use. I'm looking for something more advanced which is best described in my comments in the array sample below.

When a document and id are the same but the revision number is different then that is not a duplicate but, if we see 2 different document numbers using the same id then that is a duplicate. Basically document to id are 1 to 1.

Thoughts? Thanks!

See below:

```
arr = [
{document: "200", revision: "1", id: "1"}, // -> duplicate, because of revision 1 & id combo
{document: "200", revision: "2", id: "1"}, // -> not a duplicate, because of revision 2 & id combo
{document: "200", revision: "1", id: "1"}, // -> duplicate because it is revision 1 & id combo
{document: "200", revision: "3", id: "1"}, // -> not a duplicate, because of revision 2 & id combo
{document: "200", revision: "4", id: "1"}, // -> not a duplicate, because of revision 2 & id combo
{document: "201", revision: "1", id: "2"}, // -> standard duplicate as all 3 columns are the same for id 2 + document 203 is using the same id 2
{document: "201", revision: "1", id: "2"}, // -> standard duplicate as all 3 columns are the same for id 2 + document 203 is using the same id 2
{document: "201", revision: "2", id: "2"}, // -> this is a duplicate because document 203 is using the same id 2
{document: "203", revision: "3", id: "2"}, // -> this is a duplicate because document 201 is using the same id 2
];

// find duplicates 
function getDuplicates(arr) {
    const seen = new Set();

    const filteredArr = arr.filter(el => {
        const duplicate = seen.has(el.document + "_" + "_" + el.revision + "_" + el.id);
        seen.add(el.document + "_" + "_" + el.revision + "_" + el.id);
        return duplicate;
    });
    return filteredArr;
}

filteredArr  = [
    {document: "200", revision: "1", id: "1"},
    {document: "200", revision: "1", id: "1"},
    {document: "201", revision: "1", id: "2"}, 
    {document: "201", revision: "1", id: "2"},
    {document: "201", revision: "2", id: "2"},
    {document: "203", revision: "3", id: "2"},
    ];
```

Comment: I don't quite get it: *'...document to id are 1 to 1'* which sounds to me that there're only 2 essential properties - `revision` and `id`. But at the same time, you marked as duplicates 2 last items having unique `revision`-`id` combination based on the fact, they have a ***single*** common property (`id`).

Comment: Well document and id are unique, 2 different document numbers cannot share the same id so therefore that's a duplicate is what I meant by that.